# Replace (Entity Framework Connection) to (WebServices) on Services Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, architecture, entity-framework-4

We have the following structure on our project in order to get data.

Acces to Database Using Entity Framework

- ProjectName.DAL

Services that call Entity Framework.(UoW)

- ProjectName.Service

Our Actions inside Controllers call Services and return data needed.

- ProjectName.Web

**The Question:**

Our services take info directly with Entity Framework, **What are the advantages and disadvantages about creating WebServices in order to replace the connection with EF?** "In that case only WebServices will have access to Entity Framework,"

- ProjectName.DAL
- ProjectName.WebServices
- ProjectName.Service
- ProjectName.Web

Answer (score 2):

The main advantage is that you would have a more **decoupled design**.

By exposing your DAL through web services you "disconnect" it from your frontend. For example, a mobile app, a web app and a WPF desktop app could all access your DAL through the same web services. So you can reuse your DAL accross different apps which can save you a lot of development time. Have a look at [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) and [advantages of its web services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Advantages-of-message-based-web-services).

Disadvantages? Having to do some **additional development work and testing**. If your app is a simple and will not be used in different environments it may be overkill to use web services.

Comment: ServiceStack looks great!(I learn something new every day) At the moment we don't need to share data with other apps. But we would like to set the "best" structure, maybe you are right and if we set WebServices in that case we will be overkilling the app. -.-'

Answer (score 1):

**Disadvantages:**

*Web services* tend to consume more resources from your server than just a plain CLR (aka dll) layer in your project.
whatever web service you plan to use (legacy web services, service stack, wcf, Web API, etc) you'll find that all of them have to use a process to serialize the data and it could be the case that you'll need to do the inverse process in your front end application.

you have to design your ws very carefully because you have to think how you're going to expose those services and the level of encapsulation/abstraction you will have to put in place, a bad design in a web service layer definetely will be a headache for you during development and  production.

Security: In most cases you will have to validate every input in those web services as well

**Advantages**
well that's very relative to call an advantage, it depends more on what are your app requirements, some questions you need to answer are like the following:

- Do I need to share data with other apps (mobile, desktop, other web
  apps)?
- Do I need to expose some functionalities to other business    (third
  parties)?

**Recomendation**
If you plan to do a CRUD application I'll recomend to go with REST definetely is the best option due to it's architecture (POST,DELETE,GET,ETC).

if you don't need you a web service right now, you can try to develop your service layer kind of like a service implementation in service stack but try to remain as POCO as possible and if for some reason you'll need a web service you can try to refector the service layer intead to have another level of indirection in the middle.

just my two cents...

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply!! very useful information, I'll follow your advise!